# Locales with ISO calendar only

Tags: java, calendar, locale

I have a java program where the user can choose the locale which he wants from a checkbox. in order to populate this checkbox I use the `Calendar.getAvailableLocales()` method. The problem is that this method returns locales which use dates which are not Gregorian and this causes problems in my program which only supports Gregorian dates (ISO). Two examples are the Japanese (Japan, jP) locale and the Thai (Thailand, TH) locale. I do not want these types of locales to appear in the program. How can I filter the list such that only locales with ISO calendar formats are available in the checkbox? Thanks.

EDIT:
Ok. Here is the code for the `JLocaleChooser` combo box that I use:

```
locales = Calendar.getAvailableLocales();
localeCount = locales.length;
for (int i = 0; i < localeCount; i++) {
  if (locales[i].getCountry().length() > 0) {
      addItem(locales[i].getDisplayName());
      
  }
}
```

After that I set the locale of the system based on the user choice as such:

```
myLocale2 = theJLocaleChooser.getLocale();
Locale.setDefault(myLocale2);
```

If the user chooses the Japanese (Japan) locale then everything is fine. if he/she chooses the Japanese (Japan, JP) locale my program does not perform operations like it should. For example, somewhere in the program I get the current month and use the information in a sql statement as such:

```
Calendar cal0 = Calendar.getInstance();
int month1 = cal0.get(Calendar.MONTH);
month1++; //since 0 is january
int year1 = cal0.get(Calendar.YEAR);
connect.query = "SELECT name1, name2 FROM table1 WHERE MONTH(date) = " + month1 + " AND YEAR(date) = " + year1;
```

This sql query returns an empty dataset if the user chose Japanese(Japan, JP) but returns the correct dataset if the user chose the Japanese(Japan) locale. The reason is that the value of the year1 variable if I use the Japanese (Japan, JP) locale is 26 (I used a `println` command) but it is 2014 (like it should be) if I use other locales including the Japanese (Japan) one. Therefore I need locales that use the "regular" years (2012, 2013,...) not other years (like the Islamic Hijra for example).

Comment: It's unclear whether you're actually talking about the Gregorian calendar or the ISO textual format. I've just tried `Calendar.getInstance(Locale.JAPAN)` and it's still returned a Gregorian calendar - can you say exactly what you mean by "not supporting" Gregorian dates?

Comment: I have edited the question in order to provide you with more information.

Comment: Well this sounds like it's about SQL rather than anything else then - and you haven't told us anything about the database or what's stored in it...

Comment: Its not about sql. The year1 variable has a value of 26 when it should have a value of 2014. This is why the sql query is returning an empty dataset; no records satisfy the condition of having a year of 26. The year1 variable is generated in the java code after I set the locale.

Comment: So what is the type of the variable `cal0` refers to? (As I said, in my test of `Calendar.getInstance(Locale.JAPAN)` I was still getting a `GregorianCalendar`) You're not even specifying the locale in the code using `cal0`... are you setting the default locale based on the user's choice? It would really help if you'd show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem - just a console app showing a non-Gregorian calendar based on locale.

Comment: Ah, I've now seen the bit about it working for Japan, but not for Japanese... will try that.

Comment: It seems there are *three* Japanese locales, at least on my system - anyway, I've worked out what you mean now.

Comment: By the way, calling `Locale.setDefault` is not usually recommended. That command affects all code running in all threads in all apps running in that JVM even as they are executing. Better to store the desired Locale object, and use it to specify wherever a Locale is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will modify the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just check whether `Calendar.getInstance(Locale)` returns a `GregorianCalendar`:

```
for (Locale locale : Calendar.getAvailableLocales()) {
  if (locale.getCountry().length() > 0
      && Calendar.getInstance(locale) instanceof GregorianCalendar) {
    addItem(locale.getDisplayName());
  }
}
```